# Stata: list only few number of records with condition

Tags: list, stata

I would like to list only few numbers of records with some conditions. Problem: if I use in 1/4 or _n <= 4 and the first 4 records do not satisfy the condition no records are listed. Here is an example:

```
clear
input x
1
2
3
4
5
6
end
list if x > 4  & _n <= 3
list in 1/3 if x > 4
```

Does anybody has an idea how can be solved this problem in one line?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Nick Cox took an interest in this question and posted another solution on Statalist: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-11/msg00445.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following code into a file named slist.ado in directory where Stata can see it (like ~/ado/personal). You can find such directories with the -adopath- command.

```
program define slist 
version 12.1
syntax [varlist] [if], top(int)

#delimit;
tempvar tag;
gen `tag'=1 `if';
sort `tag';
list `varlist' `if' in 1/`top';

end;
```

The syntax is `slist x if x>4, top(4)`. The if you don't specify x, it will give you all the variables in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a little surprised that we have to program ourselves such an important functio.

Comment: I must say that in my ~12 years as a Stata user, I have never wanted to do something like this.